# Invalid operation: language plpgsql not supported for CREATE FUNCTION

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbeaver

I am trying to validate dates in string type column in my table. I wrote function to check date format and then procedure to get all no- valid values in separate table. But my function is not working and giving this error: "Invalid operation: language plpgsql not supported for CREATE FUNCTION".

Here's my function:

```
create or replace function public.valid_date(p_str varchar(50))
returns boolean as $$
begin
    perform p_str::date;
    return true;
    exception when others then
    return false;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: your function `valid_date` is working well, no error message on my side !

Comment: Seems `plpgsql` can only be used for `CREATE PROCEDURE` not `CREATE FUNCTION` in Redshift. See here [Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html) and [Procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html)

Comment: @EdouardH. yes it will work fine, but not working in redshift as it only allows user defined functions. I need to convert this to the user defined one.

Comment: No, Redshift only allows using `plpgsql` in a `PROCEDURE` not a `FUNCTION`.